# Adding a javaScript inside my sharepoint master page , to un-chekc a check box has chnage the page title

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have added the following JavaScript to my sharepoint master page , :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DefaultUploadOverwriteOff() {
  if (document.title= "Upload a document" ) {
    var input=document.querySelectorAll("input");
    for (var i=input.length; i--;) {
      if (input[i].id.search(/\_OverwriteSingle$|\_OverwriteMultiple$/) > -1) input[i].checked=false
    }
  }
}
function DefaultUploadOverwriteOff2() {
  if (document.title= "Upload Image" ) {
    var input=document.querySelectorAll("input");
    for (var i=input.length; i--;) {
      if (input[i].id.search(/\_OverwriteSingle$|\_OverwriteMultiple$/) > -1) input[i].checked=false
    }
  }
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('DefaultUploadOverwriteOff');
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('DefaultUploadOverwriteOff2');
</script>
```

the idea was to always uncheck the "overwrite existing files" check box when uploading images or document inside a page, as foolow:-

[image]

The script did the work in un-checking the check-box, but i noticed that the page title inside the browser will always be "Upload Image" after adding the scrit, as follow:-

[image]

can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug lies here:

```
if (document.title= "Upload Image" ) { /*...*/ }
```

The correct code should be:

```
if (document.title == "Upload Image" ) { /*...*/ }
```

If you want to compare in an 'IF' statement, you need to use '==' or '===' to evaluate if the condition equals the string.  In your current code, instead of comparing the title and the string, you set the title to the string "Upload Image".

You have the same bug in the "Upload a document" comparison as well.